# Recover temporary files Stata

Tags: stata, temporary-files

How do I recover a temporary Stata file? My computer crashed when I had been working on a .do file for quite a while and I found a [pretty good explanation](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2004-01/msg00542.html) of what temporary files are and why they are there, but no word on how to open them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

If you type in Stata

```
tempfile foo
di "`foo'"
```

then Stata will show you the name it has allocated for a temporary file (which does not yet exist). The important part is the filepath, which will show you where Stata stores temporary files on your system. Now it is between you and your operating system to find those files if they still exist. Whether they are as you wish them to be is a different question.

Alternatively,

```
di "`c(tmpdir)'"
```

will get you that information. I explain this second, because the thought process behind the first solution should be less esoteric. The puzzle is: Where does Stata put temporary files? The answer is: Create one, and see where it is on the system. (In fact, we do not need really to create one, just assign a handle.)

In fact the email you cite from Alan Riley does explain this. But the main question here is how do I *recover* files, and the answer does depends on what the temporary file(s) are holding. If they are text files, Stata's `doedit` or any text editor will do.

But if you are expecting that Stata saves the do-file editor window contents in a temporary file of its own, independently of any `tempfile` declaration made by you, and in a form that you can recover the contents, then my guess is that you will find nothing. If there is stuff, it will be in the directory or folder identified.

Comment: Thanks for your response Nick, retrieving the files is indeed not the problem. It just seems that Stata hardly stores anything in them. I managed to recover about 7 lines of code in three different .tmp files out of more than 200. I'm in touch with Alan Riley who has made some suggestions. Once he gets back to me, I'll post a response myself

Comment: You saved me one whole day. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is at least one possibility to recover (part of) a "lost" do-file.

When we are writing a do-file, we usually run it along the way, just to make sure everything is going as planned. When running an unsaved do-file, Stata automatically saves it in a temporary file, found in the temp directory (@Nick has already explained how to find it). So, if you were working with a do-file, then at least the last version you executed should be there. Use any text editor to open it.

Comment: Hi Roberto, I was working with a do-file and I did run it (and saved the results thank God) a couple of times but that file seems to be impossible to recover. I've asked Alan for advice so perhaps i'll be able to get it back and let you guys know how it works. One of the temp files is 65 kB, but that's the biggest one so not sure if it will work